# How to return value from Component to VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have requirement to return sobject from Component's repeat loop to main page in which component is used. And in main VF page i want to just display the field and its value.

Note: all this happening on page Load.

I am not sure whether it's possible or not?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution for this now , 
I used variable attribute from the component and in var attribute there is a type tag in which i selected Sobject and hence i was able to solve my problem. it was as simple.

So, From the VF page i can Access the value using value of "var" (new Attribute created in Component) which i passed in Component.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. There's article describing how to achive [that](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication).

Comment: Please don't use link only answers. Include at least an overview of what you're linking to, in case the link later breaks.